# 3 players game theory formulation

Tags: game-theory

I really confused about the formal representation of three players game theory formulation. I read several references and find a big difference in these references. I want some help to write the right formulation for pure Nash equilibrium using 3 players game theory. 
the second question is when I find more than one Nash, how can I select the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the game below with 3 players. Analyzing this game with three players is quite interesting. A three-dimensional array of cells, each with three payoffs, would be the best method to present them. But writing this down on a two-dimensional piece of paper is challenging. Consequently, a game of dimensions *n×m×l* is often presented as *l* distinct *n×m* matrices. In the given scenario, consider the following perspective:

• Player 1 selects a row (upper row A or lower row B).

• Player 2 chooses for a column (left column A or right column B).

• Player 3 makes a choice of matrix (upper matrix A or lower matrix B).

To emphasize the best payoff for Player 3, you need to compare the player-3-payoffs for each of the 4 combinations of choices made by Players 1 and 2 (each corresponding to a cell in the matrices). For instance, in the **(A, A)** cell, highlight the 70 from the upper matrix, surpassing the 60 in the lower matrix. In the **(A, B)**-cell, highlight 23, which is greater than 0, and so forth. Ultimately, the **(A, A)**-cell in the upper matrix (related to the choice of A by Player 3) will feature all three payoffs highlighted. The same holds for the **(B, B)**-cell in the upper matrix (again tied to the choice of A by Player 3). Consequently, the identified pure Nash Equilibria are **(A, A, A)** and **(B, B, A)**.

[Photo of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URV4V.png)